# Linking Rust objects to one another mutably causes borrowing problems

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a group of Rust `struct` instances that represent squares on a game board. Each square knows which other squares can be reached from itself.

Here is my example:

```rust
enum Direction {
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Square {
    x: u16,
    y: u16,
}

impl Square {
    fn new(x: u16, y: u16) -> Self {
        Square { x, y }
    }
    fn spawn_another_square(&self, d: Direction) -> Self {
        let mut new_x = self.x;
        let mut new_y = self.y;
        match d {
            Direction::North => new_y -= 1,
            Direction::South => new_y += 1,
            Direction::East => new_x += 1,
            Direction::West => new_x -= 1,
        }
        Self::new(new_x, new_y)
    }
}
```

The `Square` struct has only **x** and **y** coordinates in this example, no real data. The struct implements `Debug` so we can print it, and two functions: a `new()`, and a `spawn_another_square()` that returns a new square, with the coordinates of this one, but shifted north, south, east or west as desired.

If we add a `main()` to test this part, it works.

```rust
fn main() {
    let northern_square = Square::new(10, 10);
    let central_square = northern_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::South);
    let western_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::West);
    let eastern_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::East);
    let southern_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::South);
    println!("Northern square: {:?}", northern_square);
    println!("Central square: {:?}", central_square);
    println!("Western square: {:?}", western_square);
    println!("Eastern square: {:?}", eastern_square);
    println!("Southern square: {:?}", southern_square);
}
```

The `main` first creates the `northern_square`, using `new()`, at arbitrary coordinates **10**, **10**. This is then `spawn_another_square()`'d into a new `central_square` that is shifted `Direction::South` of the first. Then the central square is spawned to make the others. You get the idea.

Next step is to add information about the paths that exist between squares.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Square {
    x: u16,
    y: u16,
    to_the_north: Option<&Square>,
    to_the_south: Option<&Square>,
    to_the_east: Option<&Square>,
    to_the_west: Option<&Square>,
}
impl Square {
    fn new(x: u16, y: u16) -> Self {
        Square {
            x,
            y,
            to_the_north: None,
            to_the_south: None,
            to_the_east: None,
            to_the_west: None,
        }
    }
    fn spawn_another_square(&self, d: Direction) -> Self {
        let mut new_x = self.x;
        let mut new_y = self.y;
        match d {
            Direction::North => new_y -= 1,
            Direction::South => new_y += 1,
            Direction::East => new_x += 1,
            Direction::West => new_x -= 1,
        }
        // neighbour squares will be None on new square, even if set on this square
        Self::new(new_x, new_y)
    }
}
```

Here we can see four new elements of the struct, to record which square you will find in each of the four directions. The new elements are `Option<&Square>`, since it is possible for there to be no square at all in some directions, and so that the `Square` instances can be created before the path information is known. Also, we don't want the squares to own one another, only to point to one another; it wouldn't be possible for east and west both to own central. Also, the `new()` function has been  updated to supply the `None` values for the new elements.

Of course my example doesn't compile because `expected named lifetime parameter`, so let's fix that...

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Square<'a> {
    x: u16,
    y: u16,
    to_the_north: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
    to_the_south: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
    to_the_east: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
    to_the_west: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Square<'a> {
    fn new(x: u16, y: u16) -> Self {
        Square {
            x,
            y,
            to_the_north: None,
            to_the_south: None,
            to_the_east: None,
            to_the_west: None,
        }
    }
    fn spawn_another_square(&self, d: Direction) -> Self {
        let mut new_x = self.x;
        let mut new_y = self.y;
        match d {
            Direction::North => new_y -= 1,
            Direction::South => new_y += 1,
            Direction::East => new_x += 1,
            Direction::West => new_x -= 1,
        }
        // neighbour squares will be None on new square, even if set on this square
        Self::new(new_x, new_y)
    }
}
```

It compiles, but it looks like a lot of extra `<'a>`s.

Now to try setting some paths, with a new function implemented on the `Square` struct, and an updated `main()`. Here's the whole thing:

```rust
enum Direction {
    North,
    South,
    East,
    West,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Square<'a> {
    x: u16,
    y: u16,
    to_the_north: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
    to_the_south: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
    to_the_east: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
    to_the_west: Option<&'a Square<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Square<'a> {
    fn new(x: u16, y: u16) -> Self {
        Square {
            x,
            y,
            to_the_north: None,
            to_the_south: None,
            to_the_east: None,
            to_the_west: None,
        }
    }
    fn spawn_another_square(&self, d: Direction) -> Self {
        let mut new_x = self.x;
        let mut new_y = self.y;
        match d {
            Direction::North => new_y -= 1,
            Direction::South => new_y += 1,
            Direction::East => new_x += 1,
            Direction::West => new_x -= 1,
        }
        Self::new(new_x, new_y) // neighbour squares will be None on new square, even if set on this square
    }
    fn set_a_path(&mut self, dir: Direction, dest: &'a Square) {
        match dir {
            Direction::North => self.to_the_north = Some(dest),
            Direction::South => self.to_the_south = Some(dest),
            Direction::East => self.to_the_east = Some(dest),
            Direction::West => self.to_the_west = Some(dest),
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut northern_square = Square::new(10, 10);
    let mut central_square = northern_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::South);
    let mut western_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::West);
    let mut eastern_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::East);
    let mut southern_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::South);

    northern_square.set_a_path(Direction::South, &central_square);

    println!("Northern square: {:?}", northern_square);
    println!("Central square: {:?}", central_square);
    println!("Western square: {:?}", western_square);
    println!("Eastern square: {:?}", eastern_square);
    println!("Southern square: {:?}", southern_square);
}
```

This works, changing all the square's variables to be `mut`able, then setting a path with `set_a_path()` from the `northern_square`, heading South, to the `central_square`. This runs OK.

But adding extra paths causes my problem. One more line in main is enough.

```rust
central_square.set_a_path(Direction::East, &eastern_square);
```

This causes the error.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `central_square` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:51:5
   |
49 |     northern_square.set_a_path(Direction::South, &central_square);
   |                                                  --------------- immutable borrow occurs here
50 |   //  central_square.set_a_path(Direction::North, &northern_square);
51 |     central_square.set_a_path(Direction::East, &eastern_square);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
...
54 |     println!("Northern square: {:?}", northern_square);
   |                                       --------------- immutable borrow later used here
```

Am I completely on the wrong path? Am I going about this in an 'object oriented' way, and not a sufficiently Rusty way? Or am I close, maybe just missing the odd `&` `ref` `mut` `*` combination?

The square variables need to be mutable, to add the references to the other squares. I don't think we could create the squares with the paths already coded in, because the first square's neighbours would not have been created in time for it to receive its info.

Comment: Any design that includes circular references is just asking for trouble in Rust. If fields have references to their neighbors, circular references are inevitable.

Comment: "Each square knows which other squares can be reached from itself." – that's the cause of your issues. Rust isn't OO, and trying to shoehorn an OO approach like this won't work.

Comment: Rust is multi-paradigm, which includes OO. And most of the crates use an OO approach to design (more or less). So an OO approach *will* work if done correctly - or even sloppily =) . Generally, when developing an elegant OO architecture for an application, one trades some performance to get there. If done well, the code can be easy for others to understand and maintain. If not done well, it can be a bloated mess. I personally prefer a hybrid approach to design.

Comment: I agree with Todd much more than Lambda Fairy. Thanks both.

Answer (score 1):

#### Quick Fix

For the immediate problem your Q ends with, the fix is very simple. You just need to declare the instance you need to mutate later as `mut` (see comments in code below).

#### More Info

**Sharing references between instances is fine as long as you don't need to mutate the shared-referenced instances after they've been multiply shared. Or, if you're cloning/copying instances in lieu of sharing references, you'll be okay.**

If we were really implementing a game board, we could avoid the need for shared references in the fields of `square`s by using array/`Vec` indices instead. If we had a single "board" instance that owned an array or `Vec` that owned all the squares. Fields like `to_the_north` could have type `usize` instead of a reference. Or, some sort of *handle* object based internally on array position could work.

Also, implementing the board as an array-like type is a type of optimization. With the way data is cached by the processor, "locality" of contiguous data can make sequential access very quick. This would be better than implementing the board as a web of references to heap allocated instances that aren't necessarily contiguous.

If something like the above simple design won't work (array with indices/handles), and if you do intend to share *MUTABLE* references between these `square`s, then you'll need to leverage Rust's smart pointer classes/structs. With Rust's borrowing rules, in many cases, the alternatives to using the smart pointers are less than desirable. The usage model for Rust generally expects the use of the smart pointer classes where mutable shared access is needed.

The relevant smart pointer classes are:

- `Rc` - multiple owners; reference counted.
- `RefCell` - single owner; mutable interior.

These are typically nested as `Rc<RefCell<...>>`. Or if you only need ref counted multiple owner access to an instance (without interior mutability), you'll only need `Rc<...>`. `RefCell<...>` can also be used independently where it has only has one owner, and the encapsulated item needs to be modified on demand, despite the object owning the `RefCell` itself being immutable.

For instances of classes shared between threads, the thread-safe analogs for the above are `Arc` (vs `Rc`) and `Mutex` (vs `RefCell`).

#### Caveat - circular references

A `Vec`/array implementation using indices as handles instead of refs avoids the following issue.

If you were to have `square` instances holding `Rc<...>` references to each other, you'll likely get memory cycles. And the reference counts in cycles may not ever decrement to 0, in which case if you're creating board after board, and even if they go out of scope, there may be some lingering heap-allocated ref-counted objects building up over time.

This may not matter if your application only ever creates one single board and uses that for the duration.

Among the solutions for handling this case are use of weak pointers. You can read more on how to deal with potential memory cycles [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html)

```
fn main()
{
    let northern_square = Square::new(10, 10);
    
    // Add 'mut'
    let mut central_square = northern_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::South);
    
    let western_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::West);
    let eastern_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::East);
    let southern_square = central_square.spawn_another_square(Direction::South);
    
    // Now this is okay.
    central_square.set_a_path(Direction::East, &eastern_square);
    
    println!("Northern square: {:?}", northern_square);
    println!("Central square: {:?}", central_square);
    println!("Western square: {:?}", western_square);
    println!("Eastern square: {:?}", eastern_square);
    println!("Southern square: {:?}", southern_square);    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's interesting. I see that you can do this by keeping all the squares in some sort of 'array' and recording which knows about which using the array indices instead of storing references. I think I've tried not to do that sort of thing - it feels old! It feels like what we might have done with older languages, before structs/classes/objects/whatever were available; stitching together the contents of different arrays, hoping that the relevant data is still all at the same index, and noones change has move the phone number, but the left the address behind.

Comment: As for the fancy pointers - I'd sort of assumed they were for doing really sophisticated things. This doesn't seem like to unlikely a structure. It feels like it belongs in the capabilities of the 'simple' aspects of the language.

Comment: But, I am happy to be proved wrong. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Sam yeah.. Rust is a complex language where assumptions we've applied to other languages are brought to the front of our minds for reevaluation. Using indices isn't necessarily an archaic technique for primitive languages. Where skillfully applied, it can result in very efficient implementations for features.  With Rust, it' can be a viable alternative to shared references in many cases.  But for cases where you need shared references, just treat the smart pointer classes as part of the language.

Comment: @Sam using arrays does not mean that you have to store different fields in distinct arrays. You can have an array of structs that keep all the fields together. That being said, most modern games store data in an [Entity-Component-System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system), which is basically distinct arrays for each field, and gives much better performance than other models on modern hardware.

Comment: Thanks both. I agree with what you're both saying. I just didn't get there intuitively.